# How are Generalized Authentication Combinators Documented with swagger2 and servant

Tags: haskell, swagger, servant

I have a custom Authentication mechanism that I would like to have be compatible with my swagger docs output by servant-swagger.

```
data AuthUser = AuthUser 
  { auth_user_id :: Int64 
  , auth_user_email :: Text
  } deriving (Eq, Show, Generic)

type instance AuthServerData (AuthProtect "JWT") = AuthUser
```

This is coming in an Authorization Header. I currently am getting the following error:

```
    • No instance for (HasSwagger
                         (Servant.API.Experimental.Auth.AuthProtect "JWT"
                          Servant.API.Sub.:> Servant.API.Verbs.Get
                                               '[Servant.API.ContentTypes.JSON] Int))
```

For this route:

```
:<|> "todo" :> AuthProtect "JWT" :> ReqBody '[JSON] NewTodo :> Post '[JSON] Int64
```

Is there any documentation for writing the HasSwagger instance for Generalized Auth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `servant-swagger` just hasn't added the necessary instance to make that work yet, probably since it's still marked as experimental. If you're writing a program and not a library, then you can add this orphan instance to make it work:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

instance HasSwagger sub => HasSwagger (AuthProtect tag :> sub) where
  toSwagger _ = toSwagger (Proxy :: Proxy sub)
```

Note that that's a stub instance that will make it "work" as in compile, but it won't generate any mention of the authentication in the documentation. If you want that, you'd have to write a real implementation of `toSwagger`. If you want to do that, [the rest of the instances](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/servant-swagger-1.1.7.1/docs/Servant-Swagger.html#t:HasSwagger) will probably be a useful starting point.